# is there an objective-c "equivalent" to ruby's send method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ruby

I'm not sure this is possible, but in ruby, you can dynamically call a method using send

e.g. if I want to invoke the ***bar*** method for the object, ***foo***, I can use

```
foo.send("bar")
```

Is there any way of doing something similar using objective-c?

tks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several options, as far as I know

1. You could use NSObject's [`performSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:) method. This, however, is only really good for methods that have few or no arguments.
2. Use the [NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSInvocation) class. This is a bit heftier, but is a lot more flexible.
3. You might be able to use [`objc_msgSend()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH104), but it's probably a bad idea to call it directly, due to other stuff that the runtime might be doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Right, there's only `performSelector:`, `performSelector:withObject:`, and `performSelector:withObject:withObject:` -- more than 2 arguments and it's no longer a viable choice.  I think NextSTEP used to have a `performv:` allowing for variable args, or something like that, but I'm not quite sure...

Comment: More than two arguments is when you use NSInvocation, or switch to using a dictionary as an argument.  It's not that hard, it's just a few more calls.

Comment: Also, 1. is also only good if the argument types are all objects and return type is object or void

Answer (score 3):

For general use (method with a return value and any number of arguments), use [NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation%5FClass/Reference/Reference.html#//apple%5Fref/occ/cl/NSInvocation):

```
if ([target respondsToSelector:theSelector]) {
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
        [target methodSignatureForSelector:theSelector]];
    [invocation setTarget:target];
    [invocation setSelector:theSelector];
    // Note: Indexes 0 and 1 correspond to the implicit arguments self and _cmd, 
    // which are set using setTarget and setSelector.
    [invocation setArgument:arg1 atIndex:2]; 
    [invocation setArgument:arg2 atIndex:3];
    [invocation setArgument:arg3 atIndex:4];
    // ...and so on
    [invocation invoke];
    [invocation getReturnValue:&retVal]; // Create a local variable to contain the return value.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if ([foo respondsToSelector:@selector(bar)])
    [foo performSelector:@selector(bar))];
```